# How to save customized field of sales_flat_quote_items table's in sales_flat_order_item table?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, sales-order, sales-quote

How to save customized field of  **sales_flat_quote_items** table's in **sales_flat_order_item** table?

```
 <fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <recipients_name>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </recipients_name>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <recipients_name>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
        </recipients_name>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <recipients_email>
            <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
        </recipients_email>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <recipients_email>
            <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
        </recipients_email>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
```

But no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app\code\local\Test\Gifts\etc\config.xml

```
 <global> 
  <fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_item>
        <recipients_name><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></recipients_name>
        <recipients_email><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></recipients_email>
        <recipients_mobile><to_order_item>*</to_order_item></recipients_mobile>
    </sales_convert_quote_item>
    <sales_convert_order_item>
        <recipients_name><to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item></recipients_name>
        <recipients_email><to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item></recipients_email>
         <recipients_mobile><to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item></recipients_mobile>
    </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldsets>
</global>
```